# I'm using Javascript Plugin Imagenote js to put pin on image it working fine but pin changes its exact position on zoomin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

[image: please attached image here. I placed pin on image using imagenotes plugin but when i zoomin, pin changes its location.]
html :

```
<div id="droppable">
       <img src="str.png" id="dropimage" class="img-responsive" alt="..." class="pin" style=";opacity: 1;"/>
</div>
```

please find javascript code below. I assigned dropimage to image and passed x , y to place pin.  its works find but when i'm zooming image. pin should not change it position.

script :

```
$(function () {
    var notes = [
                { x: "0.26", y: "0.31033332824707033", note: "please do work" },
                { x: "0.39375", y: "0.88328", note: "please do work" },
    ];
    var $img = $("#dropimage").imgNotes({});
    $img.imgNotes("option", "canEdit", true);
    $img.imgNotes("option", "zoomable", true);
    $img.imgNotes("option", "dragable", true);
    $img.imgNotes("import", notes);

    $(".pin-red").draggable();
});
```

Comment: There are many ImageNote plugins available, which one you are using?

Comment: I'm using imageNote.js plugin. https://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-For-Adding-Notes-Markers-To-An-Image-imgNotes.html